# Controller using the wrong namespace - Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, namespace

I am working on developing a managed package (Package A) that integrates with a another managed package downloaded form the AppExchange (Package B). By integrate I mean, creating VF pages with the controller that is from Package B and an extension from Package A.

I am doing all this in the packaging org, i.e. the dev org where I am creating managed package A.

On page load everything is fine, however when I call a action method from the page I get Apex class not found error. E.g.

> Apex class 'packageB_namespace.PackageA_Class' does not exist.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet with your question please. I'm thinking it might be a platform bug or maybe a profile permissions thing, though I assume your logged in as admin?

Comment: Is the extension in Package A global? You will not be able to use any code in Package A unless it is declared as global.

Comment: Apologies for responding late, currently I am think there is an issue with the way we are using ApexPages.currentPage() from package B that might be causing the confusion. Will update when I have something concrete.

Comment: Finally got to the bottom of this, Package B had known bugs that were causing the namespace confusion. A patch has been pushed by the developers of Package B, and now everything is working :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, I believe there are security limitations that keep two managed packaged components of different namespaces from accessing one-another's code.

*If this were the case, one could theoretically create a 2nd package with a security exploit for the 1st.* - This is the reasoning for why I don't believe this is possible.

I've seen *extension packages* mentioned in the documentation, however, I haven't seen one functioning in practice (unless one is unmanaged).

Comment: Thanks Jordan, It all depends on what is in 1st package I guess along with the access of the classes. We have this working now. I might write a blog post one day and share the link.